# How to subset in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset

I want to remove "No Preference" and "Uncommitted" from my ggplot Heatmap on the y axis, but the subset just doesn't work, do you know the possible reasons ?

My code:

```
ggplot(subset(primary_results, candidate != c("No Preference", 
"Uncommitted"))) + 
geom_tile(aes(y = candidate, x = state_abbreviation, fill = fraction_votes))  
+ 
scale_fill_viridis(option = "plasma") +
theme_solarized_2() +
xlab("State") +
ylab("Candidate") +
guides(fill = guide_legend(title="Fraction Votes"))
```

My Heatmamp (notice, I still get the unwanted part)

[image: My Heatmamp (notice, I still get the unwanted part)]

If I try the subset outside the plot, it also just doesn't work..

Comment: There is no problem with `subset` in `ggplot2`. The problem might be in your data. Could you provide us some data (`dput`) ?

Comment: `!candidate %in% c("No Preference", "Uncommitted")`  try that instead

Comment: There is a small problem with the data, if you run `levels(primary_results$candidates)` you can find that there is a trailing space in both values, you can either add the space to @Mhairi's answer or run `stringr::str_trim` on the variable. Cheers

Comment: `subset(primary_results, candidate %nin% c("No Preference", " Uncommitted"))` is another solution. As mentionned by @donlelek, there is trailing space before ` Uncommitted`, source of the error.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your subset. You have removed all candidates not equal to the length two character vector `c("No Preference", "Uncommitted")`.

I think you want:

```
ggplot(subset(primary_results, !(candidate %in% c("No Preference", "Uncommitted")))) +
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, but still doesn't work, dunno why.. The data can be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/benhamner/2016-us-election, I'm working with the primary_results.csv

Comment: Hm, odd. It might be a problem with factor variables (try stringsAsFactors = FALSE). Can edit the question to show the minimum code from reading the file in to making this plot?